# c++ template pack expansion / variadic arguments

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I've got this code, which does work:

```
auto thev = std::static_pointer_cast<Thevenin>(
    add(new Thevenin(N("cntl"), N("gnd"), 1.0)));
auto det1 = std::static_pointer_cast<Detector>(
    add(new Detector(N("vout"), N("gnd"), N("eout"), N("oout"), 0)));
auto det2 = std::static_pointer_cast<Detector>(
    add(new Detector(N("cntl"), N("gnd"), N("ein"),  N("oin"), 0)));
```

However, I don't like having to specify the type twice.  It seems that variadic templates would allow me to write something like:

```
auto thev = tfun(Thevenin, N("cntl"), N("gnd"), 1.0);
auto det1 = tfun(Detector, N("vout"), N("gnd"), N("eout"), N("oout"), 0)));
auto det2 = tfun(Detector, N("cntl"), N("gnd"), N("ein"),  N("oin"), 0)));
```

Unfortunately, the documentation on pack expansion is too terse for me, and I have been unable to write a tfun template that will compile.  Can someone show me how it's done?

Comment: Make `add` a template similar to `std::make_unique`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps you wanted to use `make_shared` that'd fit your needs? What is `add` in your case? You can look at how `make_{shared|unique}` is implemented to get an idea on how to do what you want.

Comment: You should change `add`; the fact you need a static ptr cast there is most of your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks trivial.

```
template<class RetVal, class... Args> inline auto tfun(Args &&...args) {
     return std::static_pointer_cast<RetVal>(add(new RetVal(std::forward<Args>(args)...)));
}

auto thev = tfun<Thevenin>(N("cntl"), N("gnd"), 1.0);
```